# Logitech K480 keys suddenly stopped working on OSX Catalina

Tags: keyboard, catalina, bluetooth

I was using my Logitech K480 keyboard on MBP 2019 and suddenly the following keys stopped working. I have tried the following things, but to no avail. If anyone has any ideas, please suggest!
[image: https://apple.stackexchange.com]

1. Forget device on OSX's Bluetooth menu and reconnect.
2. Tried same keys on other devices. This keyboard has a dial to connect to other devices. Same keys are not working on Iphone XR.
3. I removed my Logitech mouse's bluetooth receiver from the Mac adapter, and connected the K480 and the keys started working. However, on repeating this, the keys are not working again.

Comment: Are you using any Logitech software? Like Flow or Options? If not try to install it from here: https://support.logi.com/hc/de/articles/360024848553--Downloads-Bluetooth-Multi-Device-Keyboard-K480 and see if that helps.

Comment: Since the same issue is happening on the iPhone as well, which has a different operating system, I'd lean towards a hardware issue. Though if possible I'd test it on a non-Apple computer/device.

Comment: I know this seems obvious, but have you tried changing the batteries?

Comment: @X_841 no I am not. Let me try that.

Comment: @Joonas Have a Raspberry PI lying around, will try that.

Comment: @Salocor no luck with new batteries.